# Reincarnation manhwa in which the female lead goes back in time for revenge on her uncle

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

It’s a historical fiction with magic. The female lead was a mercenary in her past life. In it, her mom dies of an illness and she thinks her grandfather didn’t care so she kills him. But she finds out that her great uncle set her up and then her uncle kills her. She is sent back to when she was a child and her mom was still alive. She leaves and gets her grandfather to help her and she wants revenge on her uncle. She meets a small white dragon/snake at one point.

Comment: Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

Comment: I think her hair color was light brown. Could have been red. The theorized male lead has white hair.

Answer (score 3):

This is ***[The Grand Duke's Beloved Granddaughter](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-grand-dukes-beloved-granddaughter)***.

> Mirabel is a famed mercenary whose mother, Cornelia, had long suffered from the guilt of leaving her family, the Grand Dukedom of Citron behind. After Cornelia's failed attempts to contact her family left her distressed and led to her death, Mirable seeked revenge, tracking down her grandfather, the Grand Duke Criton and the assumed cause of all her mother's misery. After finding out that he too was betrayed, Mirabel meets an untimely death at the hands of the true culprit, only to wake up back when she was nine years old, with her mother still alive. Determined to stop her mother's death, and seek revenge against the true villain, Maribel sets out to make things right. But her choice to meeti her grandfather makes her cross traces of her past, while she experiences a life she never knew before.
>
> [image: Promotional art for "The Grand Duke's Beloved Granddaughter."]

The protagonist, Mirabel, is a mercenary whose mother, Cornelia, left her family for love. After Mirabel was born, her father, Gyle, died protecting the village she grew up in, leaving Cornelia to raise her alone. Cornelia wrote letters to her father, Grand Duke Criton, seeking forgiveness, but received no response and ultimately died of illness.

Some time later, the Duke summons Mirabel to his estate and asks her to find Cornelia for him. (He doesn't know about Cornelia's death or that Mirabel is his granddaughter.) Angered by his request, Mirabel asks him why he ignored the letters Cornelia sent him and tells him that she died in resentment of her father who never responded.

Then the Duke's brother and Mirabel's great uncle, Lord Daniel Criton, enters the room and reveals that he intercepted the letters sent by Cornelia to ensure that the Duke didn't forgive her and welcome her back into the fold.

> [image: Promotional art for "The Grand Duke's Beloved Granddaughter."]

Daniel is revealing this now because he intends to kill both the Duke and Mirabel tonight and has brought a bunch of armed men with him to assassinate them. The Duke tells Mirabel to run away, but she stays and fights and dies with him.

She then wakes up as her much younger self, when her mother was still alive, and vows to cure her mother's illness and enact justice on Daniel.

In chapter 3, she visits the Duke to arrange a reunion between him and her mother.

In chapter 12, she visits the temple of the goddess, Duana, hoping to learn whether she has enough divine power to save her mother. There, a saint named Pleon gives her a pendant with a white snake on it, which turns out to be alive, and is the goddess' guardian dragon, Vivre.

You can read the full manhwa at [Pocket Comics](https://www.pocketcomics.com/comic/9751).

Comment: @Marcy - If this answer is correct, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the grey check mark near the top-left corner of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.